# Edit profile name in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-accounts, meteor-autoform

I am very new to Meteor.

I am publishing users from the server with

```
Meteor.publish("users", function () {
    return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {emails: 1, profile: 1, createdAt: 1}, sort: {createdAt: -1}});
});
```

I am routing to a user profile with `iron-router`:

```
this.route('userProfile', {
  path: '/users/:_id',
  template: 'userProfile',
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('users', this.params._id);
  },
  data: function() {
    return Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
  },
});
```

I want to be able to show and edit profile name on this page. How can I best obtain this?

In my template I am showing the name with

```
<template name="userProfile">
  <h1>{{#if profile.name}}{{profile.name}}{{else}}No Name{{/if}}</h1>
</template>
```

but the object has no name yet. I guess I can make the header clickable with

```
Template.userProfile.events({
  'click h1': function(e) {
    // change <h1> to <input type="text">
  }
});
```

but I'm not sure what to do now.

Besides, is it a good idea to start using `meteor-autoform`?

Answer (score 0):

I find toggling between an input and an h1 is kind of painful so I can up with another solution (The trick here is to use a hidden span to measure the width of the text so that you can resize your input at each keypress).

Template:

```
<template name="userProfile">
  <div>
    <input  class="js-profile-name" value="{{profile.name}}" />
    <span class="js-profile-name-holder">{{profile.name}}</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

Style:

```
.js-profile-name {
    /* we style our input so that it looks the same as a H1 */
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 24px;
    outline: none;
    border: 0;
}

.js-profile-name-holder {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

JS:

```
Template.userProfile.onRendered(function () {
  this.find('.js-profile-name').style.width = this.find('.js-profile-name-holder').offsetWidth + 'px';
});

Template.userProfile.events({
  'change .js-profile-name': function (e, tmpl) {
    if (!e.target.value) {
      // prevent empty values
      tmpl.find('.js-profile-name-holder').innerHTML = this.profile.name;
      e.target.value = this.profile.name;
      e.target.style.width = tmpl.find('.js-profile-name-holder').offsetWidth + 'px';
      return;
    }

    Meteor.users.update({_id: this._id}, {
      $set: {
        'profile.name': e.target.value
      }
    });
  },
  'keypress .js-profile-name': function (e, tmpl) {
    // resize our input at each keypress so that it fits the text
    tmpl.find('.js-profile-name-holder').innerHTML = e.target.value;
    e.target.style.width = tmpl.find('.js-profile-name-holder').offsetWidth + 'px';
  }
});
```

I recognize this is quiet a bit of code for a single field, but it could easily be wrapped in a block helper and made reusable.

Answer (score -1):

```
Template.userProfile.helpers({
  /*here you can load individual user data*/
});
```